# Does 'Levi-' as half of a surname indicate a family of Levites?

Tags: names, etymology, levites-leviyim

I've come across a number of surnames of the form *Levi-[Something]*:

- [Tullio Levi-Civita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tullio_Levi-Civita) was from an Italian Jewish family.
- [Claude Lévi-Strauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_L%C3%A9vi-Strauss) was from an Alsatian Jewish family.
- [Rita Levi-Montalcini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rita_Levi-Montalcini) was from an Italian Jewish family.

Does *Levi-* as the first half of a surname generally derive from (or is it) an indication of a Levite family? (I'm asking in general, not about those three families specifically.)

Comment: My first thought is that their ancestors were a man named Levi and a woman named Civita/Strauss/Montalcini (or vice-versa).

Comment: @ba In most cases I know of, the woman's name usually comes first. I wonder if that's the case here, though; I'm not sure hyphenization was so common back when these people's parents were married.

Comment: off-topic, Epstein is, according to a friend with that name, a Levite surname.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119379

Answer (score 1):

The name levi is a big indicator, true, but don't take for granted that a name is what it says it is. For example, in my community, I know two families whose full names are Cohen and are not Kohanim. Maybe it is different by Leviim, but probably not, because it will go on the same line of logic that people adopt names (if they were fleeing a country for example) or they get mixed up at a border (like Ellis Island) or in a country's records. So although it is likely that they are what their name says, it's still wise to check a few records to make sure.

Comment: Indication =! Proof. I think the name Cohen is still an indication of being a Kohein.

Comment: @DoubleAA what do you mean still an indication - they are NOT kohanim

Comment: Meaning if you gave me someone named Cohen that I didn't know, I would bet decent money that they are a Kohein. Your examples don't disprove that. I'm guessing msh210 is asking if there is a statistically significant increase in the likelihood of someone being a Levi if half of their name is "Levi-", and I don't see how your answer addresses that.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @DoubleAA on this one. Like most people named Cohen are Kohanim, there is no doubt that most people named Levi are Leviim. As for the answer to the question about the combined name, I don't know.

Comment: That might be true but the fact that just because your name says something, you might not be it - so that whole point was disproved fine it might lead someone to believe that the person is whatever his name means. Lets say the case of someone's name being wrong is  1 in 10 or 1 in 100 you can't take it for granted they are what their name says. And as far as I could tell from the question msh210 was asking if people with the surname Levi are leviim and the answer I gave is maybe not. I'm sorry but I don't see the problem.

Comment: I don't see how you could think the question is asking for an absolute test, when he clearly says "Does Levi- as the first half of a surname **generally derive from** (or is it) an **indication of** a Levite family? (I'm asking in general, **not about those three families specifically**.)"

Comment: Since names are patrilineal and Judaism is matrilineal, it's not at all unusual (in these days of fairly common intermarriage) for a non-Jew to be named Cohen. My understanding is that a non-Jew, even with a kohein father, converted to Judaism, he or she would be considered yisrael, not kohein.