# Gemara source regarding Levy in Germania

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, levites-leviyim, golus-exile, yekke

My name is Levy.

Someone I know from France, where we have the same origins, in Alsace / Germany, and profoundly religious and an intellectual, told me that in the Gemara, it is said that after the destruction of the 1st Temple, the Tribe of Levy fled to "Germania."

This would explain our origins also in Alsace, which is know to have a very old tradition of Jews in the area, since the Middle Ages.

Where in the Gemara is this statement about Levy fleeing to Germania?

Comment: so far, I have found mentions of Germania (Mas Shabbos perek 6 - Yerushalmi) and Germamya (Yerushalmi, Megila perek 1, Bavli - Yoma perek 1 and Megila perek 1). One mention of Ashkenaz in the Yerushalmi Megila.

Comment: As a Kohen and Jekke, I would love that, but the surname Levy generally indicates levitical descent, rather than Shevet Levi having settled en-masse in Deutschland

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17834

Comment: Tangentially related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84189/15256

Comment: While you're friend said this is from the Gemara, more likely it is from a different source. You can edit your question to ask for any historical source, not necessarily the Gemara.

Comment: @rosends FYI I believe some amend the mem in Germamya to be a nun and match with the rest. My memory tells me Vilna Gaon on Megila, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I thought it was Djerba that they went to. Google Djerba Jewish History.